# Static sea rendering

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, directx

How do I program a sea like the one on the pictures below with 3D Graphics? Should I use a circular texture?

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How the scene is rendered depends a lot upon the usage scenario, in particular:

- Is this a realtime application?
- Can the camera move around?
- Should the water animate?

Assuming the answer to all these is no, the simplest approach is to render a large quad (or two triangles forming a rectangle) where the water should be.  Texture map the water quad with a seamless water texture.  For texture mapping parameters, set the texture coordinates (u/v) to be equal to the world coordinates of the corners of the quad and set the sampling method to wrap.

If copyright is not a concern you can grab a texture from [google image search](http://images.google.com/?q=water%20texture%20seamless), if it is you could try generating a texture using the [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) make seamless filter or similar.

A similar approach can be used to create the sea bed.

If you want to include the sky you might want to look into sky boxes/domes, [here](http://rastertek.com/tertut10.html) is a tutorial for DirectX.

**Edit**

When using a moving camera, you will need to base the size of the water quad on the viewable area of the camera.  The viewable area of the camera defines a 3D volume known as a [frustum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum).  From this you can calculate a rectangle which is large enough that all four corners are outside the viewable area so that no matter which way you point the camera, you can see the sea.

Psuedo code:

```
var f = camera.getFrustum()

for each point in f.getCorners()
{
    if (point.x < minimum.x) minimum.x = point.x
    if (point.z < minimum.z) minimum.z = point.z

    if (point.x > maximum.x) maximum.x = point.x
    if (point.z > maximum.z) maximum.z = point.z
}

var quad = new Quad(minimum, maximum)
```

Comment: The camera can move around and I am concerned about seeing the quad corners instead of a real horizon...

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I believe that drawing the sea in the frustum as you suggested would allow the boat to fly in the sky if you point the camera downward...

Comment: The quad's y (vertical) coordinate is constant so this should not be possible. Only the x and z coordinates are taken from the camera frustum

Comment: In this case the boat may remain on the water level but inclined, isn't it?

Comment: It is necessary that you calculate the frustum coordinates in world space, the same coordinate system that the boat is in. That way, rotation of the camera will not affect the rotation of the sea plane.